# Is there a Left,Right,Right,Right rotation in AVL tree for balancing?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I have the following keys (string type). They are inserted one at a time in this order,

> know->world->state->agent->estimate->figure->compute->symbols->bayes->model

I am getting stuck on adding figure. I have included "string[balancing factor]"
Can someone guide me if I did something wrong?

```
            state[2]
              /\
             /  \
            /    \
    estimate[-1] world[0]
        /\
       /  \
      /    \
 agent[0] know[1]
           /
          /
       figure[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your tree looks good. You'll just have to perform a rotation to make it balanced.

For reference, [this website](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/AVLtree.html) should help you visualize insertion and deletion in an AVL tree